# Define SSH hostname with subdomain, .htaccess and port

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssh

I got a machine on a local network, behind a internet box, with a NAT rule working for ssh over internet (port 245 --> machine_IP:22).
No I would like to setup a subdomain (on a domain I own) that will play the ssh hostname for this specific machine : such as ssh.subdomain.domain.com. 
So, as far as I know, I need to redirect to the box router from subdomain access. I only got htaccess choice, because it' a shared environnement.
I tried this on subdomain folder root, but it's not working :

```
RewriteEngine On
```

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://boxacces.domain:245 [L,R=301]

What should I put here to make this SSH host by subdomain worked?

Many thanks for your answers,

Nicolas

Comment: htaccess is for http server, not for ssh. you need a domain name server to resolve names.

Comment: OK thank you. Could you be more precise please? Do I need a DNS server or just a DNS entry my DNS Zone? AFAIK you can't specify port on those? Any help would be very appreciated, thanks :)